# Nested DO WHILE loop executing only once

Tags: fortran, do-while

I have the following part in my code.

```
 x=1.d0
 y=1.d0
 do while (x<5.0)
   do while (y<3.0)
      print*,'x=',x,'  y=',y
      y=y+1.d0
   end do
   print*,'x================',x
   x=x+1.d0
 end do
```

Here my intention is to vary y-value through y-do-loop for each update in x of the x-do-loop. However, after the first x-loop, y-loop does not execute anymore,  i.e. I get the following output.

```
x=   1.0000000000000000        y=   1.0000000000000000     
 x=   1.0000000000000000        y=   2.0000000000000000     
 x================   1.0000000000000000     
 x================   2.0000000000000000     
 x================   3.0000000000000000     
 x================   4.0000000000000000
```

Can't I use do while for my purpose? If yes, what modification can be done?

Comment: Don't you need to reset `y=1.d0` after you finish your x-do loop?

Comment: Put y=1.d0 between the two do whiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting the value of `y` in your outer loop, so after `y` increments to 3, it is never again less than 3. You should try:

```
x=1.d0
do while (x<5.0)
   y=1.d0
   do while (y<3.0)
      print*,'x=',x,'  y=',y
      y=y+1.d0
   end do
   print*,'x================',x
   x=x+1.d0
end do
```